# Select Data Risk classification as internal automatically

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation, titus

I am trying to send outlook mail using VBA . Every time I run my macro a pop-up comes to me of TITUS stating as select data risk classification. My question is if there any way I can bypass it or select it automatically and send an email.

I have the attempted code snippets to achieve it from multiple sources from internet below.

```
Sub test()
Dim AOMSOutlook As Object
Dim AOMailMsg As Object
Set AOMSOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim objUserProperty As Object
Set AOMailMsg = AOMSOutlook.CreateItem(0)

Set objUserProperty = AOMailMsg.UserProperties.Add("TITUSAutomatedClassification", 1)
objUserProperty.Value = "TLPropertyRoot=ABCDE;Classification=Internal;Registered to:My Companies;"
With AOMailMsg
        .To = "v-fexue@outlook.com"
        .Subject = "New Report"
        .HTMLBody = "Hi"
        .Save
        .Send
End With
Set AOMailMsg = Nothing
Set objUserProperty = Nothing
Set AOMSOutlook = Nothing
Set lOMailMsg = Nothing
Set objUserProperty = Nothing
Set lOMSOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Also please clear if `objUserProperty.Value = "TLPropertyRoot=ABCDE;Classification=Internal;Registered to:My Companies;` Registered to: (has to be actual company name)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may contact Titus developers for the actual format of the string that needs to be set to avoid any popups from their add-in in Outlook. Also you may check out the sent items for properties set by the add-in, use any low-level property explorer tool such as [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) or `OutlookSpy` for that.